# Qt - Converting QString to Unicode QByteArray

Tags: qt, unicode

I have a client-server application where client will be in Qt(Ubuntu) and server will be C#. Qt client willsend the strings in UTF-16 encoded format. 
I have used the QTextCodec class to convert to UTF-16. But whenever the conversion happens it will be padded with some more characters. For example

"<bind endpoint='2_3'/>"

will be changed to

"\ff\fe<\0b\0i\0n\0d\0 \0e\0n\0d\0p\0o\0i\0n\0t\0=\0'\02\0_\03\0'\0/\0>\0\0\0"

I have following code which converts the QString to QByteArray

```
//'socketMessage' is the QString, listener is the QTcpSocket
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-16");
QByteArray data = codec->fromUnicode(socketMessage);
listener->write(data);
```

I have even tried the QTextStream,QDataStream etc for encoding. But everytime I end up with the same result. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 7):

Though the question is asked long ago, I had the same problem. The solution to it is to create  an QTextEncoder with the option QTextCodec::IgnoreHeader.

```
QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-16");
QTextEncoder *encoderWithoutBom = codec->makeEncoder( QTextCodec::IgnoreHeader );

QString str("Foobar")
QByteArray bytes  = encoderWithoutBom ->fromUnicode( s );
```

This will result in a QByteArray without BOM.

Answer (score 2):

The \ff\fe at the beginning is the Unicode byte order mark [(BOM)](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#bom1) for UTF-16, little-endian. I'm not sure how to get the QTextCodec to ommit that but if you want to get a QByteArray from a string in UTF-16 without the BOM you could try this:

```
QString s("12345");
QByteArray b((const char*) (s.utf16()), s.size() * 2);
```