# c# utf-8 conversion problems with german umlauts

Tags: c#, qt, utf-8, thrift, thrift-protocol

I'm getting some information from a c++ backend via thrift protocol, containing a string (name) with german umlauts. Now these umlauts are displayed as questionmarks so I think I'm on the right path to try and convert them to utf-8, although thrift seems to pass strings as utf-8 anyway.

The original data comes from a postgresql database and is displayed correctly in the c++ code just before sending it to the thrift interface.

I already tried 3 different versions to convert but none of them really does anything am I'm stuck here.

Version 1:

```
private string ConvertUTF8(string str) // str == "Ha�loch, �mely"
{
  byte[] bytSrc;
  byte[] bytDestination;
  string strTo = string.Empty;

  bytSrc = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(str);
  bytDestination = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, Encoding.UTF8, bytSrc);
  strTo = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytDestination);

  return strTo; // strTo == "Ha�loch, �mely"
}
```

Version 2:

```
private string ConvertUTF8(string str) // str == "Ha�loch, �mely"
{
  byte[] bytes = str.Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray();
  return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); // == "Ha�loch, �mely"
}
```

Version 3:

```
private string ConvertUTF8(string str) // str == "Ha�loch, �mely"
{
  byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str);
  return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes); // == "Ha?loch, ?mely"
}
```

As you can see, version 3 - for whatever reason - changes the � to a regular ? but the result should be "Haßloch, Ämely". Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

edit 1:

On c++ side the string is converted from QString.toStdString() and then passed to thrift. According to QT doc the .toStdString() call includes the conversion to UTF-8 anyways (also see in top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839964/qstring-to-unicode-stdstring)). So the string should be passed correctly and thrift interface seems to also use UTF-8 internally.

edit 2:

I tried to figure out, where the first occurrence of the string would be and found this line:

```
Name = iprot.ReadString();
```

where `Name` is of type string and `iprot` is of type Thrift.Protocol.TCompactProtocol

For the `ReadString()` method, the thrift doc says `Reads a byte[] (via readBinary), and then UTF-8 decodes it` so this also can't be the reason ...

edit 3 (SOLUTION):

Marc Gravell pushed me to this ... Just replaced

```
Name = iprot.ReadString();
```

with

```
var bytes = iprot.ReadBinary();
Name = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(bytes);
```

edit 4:

even simpler:

```
var bytes = iprot.ReadBinary();
Name = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: There are no such problems in C# as you can see - StackOverflow is written in C#, the data is stored in `nvarchar` columns on SQL Server and the page encoding is UTF8. � is the Unicode replacement character. It means something, somewhere tried to read non-Unicode text using the wrong codepage. Any byte value that didn't exist in the target sequence was replaced by the error character � or `?`. `?` is produced for the same reason

Comment: How did you get `str` to start with? "Changing" an encoding like this is almost always problematic, compared with fixing how you're converting binary data to text earlier on.

Comment: BTW that `ConvertUTF8(string str) ` is meaningless - strings in Windows and .NET are UTF16, period. `Encoding.Unicode` is UTF15.  There is no UTF8 string (yet). `ConvertUTF8` will return the exact same string as its input if it works

Comment: If the *input* contains `�` it means the source data was mangled in the first place. There's no way to find what the original byte value was for that character. Where did that string come from? Post the code that reads the thrift data and converts them to a string

Comment: Which library do you use for Thrift? What encoding was used on the C++ side? UTF8 uses *two* bytes for any character outside the US-ASCII range and yet you see only *one* error character. C++ still doesn't have a UTF8 string type so it's quite possible that the data was produced using a single-byte codepage eg Latin1, by mistake. Try decoding the buffer using Windows-1253. If this is your own code, try `Encoding.Default`

Comment: The c++ part of the code sends a string with the correct value, but I'm not sure about the encoding type as that part is not my responsibilty. I'm gonna have a chat with my responsible colleague

Comment: see my edit above

Comment: @DomMa you still haven't posted how you converted that to a string. Did you use a library? Your own code to read from a byte[] buffer? All you need convert UTF8 bytes to a string is a call to `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer)`. There's nothing wrong with .NET and UTF8 as you proved by posting german characters in your question. That's why I can type Αυτό Εδώ and have no doubt it will appear correctly

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please see the second edit ... hope this helps

Comment: @DomMa `this also can't be the reason` what does `Name` contain? If it contains question marks, that's where the text gets mangled. Otherwise it's the code between that and wherever you call `ConvertUTF8`. Don't look for UTF8 incompatibilities in .NET. I don't know how to say it any other way, *your own question proves that UTF8 works just fine in .NET*. That's because you typed UTF8 characters in that question text and got them back just fine in the page. That's what Marc, one of the SO engineers tells you too

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos at this position, Name already contains the question marks ... And I understand that it should work just fine, but in my case obviously it doesn't and I'm trying to figure out why

Comment: In any case you haven't posted code that can be used to reproduce and investigate the problem. Not even a sample of the message buffer. It's easy to see whether the hex values correspond to the expected UTF8 bytes or not - all US-ASCII characters would appear as a single byte, other characters would appear as two bytes . One can only guess at this point

Comment: If you check the message as hex, `a` will appear as `0x61` while `ß` will appear as `0xc3 0x9f`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you get as far as having a `string str` input, you've **already lost the data**. `string` (`System.String`) in .NET is **always** UTF-16. You need to look upstream, at where-ever the input data came from (presumably reading from some file, byte-buffer, http-client, or database). It is *usually* simply a case of specifying the correct `Encoding` *at the point where you originally decode the data*.

You cannot fix encoding after the fact; in the code above, you've *already irretrievably lost what you wanted*.

Comment: I've added some information to the question. See the edit

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as the thrift files are auto generated and I have nothing to do with the original thrift files, I'm sorry I don't really know which part of the code you mean ...

Comment: @DomMa how are you getting hold of the data? you mention thrift, but you also mention "files" - so: are you loading the data from a file? or are you using P/Invoke? or...? basically: where do you first get the `string` in your .NET code (before you get to the bits you've posted)

Comment: @MarcGravell I hope my second edit contains useful information

Comment: @DomMa then frankly, there's a bug in the implementation of `iprot.ReadString();`, especially in how it interops with .NET; bugs happen

Comment: @MarcGravell I got it ... Problem really was the `ReadString()` method. I replaced the whole thing with `var bytes = iprot.ReadBinary();
                str = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252").GetString(bytes);` and now it works just fine. Thanks for guiding me to that solution!